How to put some text in bold in a pgn file
AS the title say, I'm trying to put some text in bold in a pgn of a study and Have no solution

PGN is intended for computer representation of a chess game using ASCII text. Standard ASCII does not have means of making things bold.
There may be programs that will process mark up inside PGN comments so that they appear in bold when displayed, but this is not part of the PGN specification.

Thanks. I've seen that the standard is not so young and understand why it's like that.
